# Rails application mailer cannot get parameter values unless page is reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently using devise gem for authentication. After user registration, an email will be sent for account confirmation. However, when the link is being clicked, an error occurs and cannot read the parameter value unless the page is being reloaded.

The error is: undefined method `[]` for nil:NilClass

[Error message when the confirmation link is being visited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NPbE.png)

When page is reloaded, the error will disappear saying that the account is already confirmed

[Page after reloaded, error message gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw5R8.png)

Here is the routes about the confirmation link

```
devise_scope :user do 
  get ":site_type/users/confirmation" => "users/confirmations#show", as: :site_confirmation
  get ":site_type/users/confirmation/new" => "users/confirmations#new", as: :site_new_confirmation
  post ":site_type/users/confirmation/new" => "users/confirmations#create", as: :site_create_confirmation
end
```

Here are the codes

Application Mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(MailerHelper)
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)
  before_action :mailer_variables
  after_action :set_default_from
  # default cc: EasySettings[:email][:cc]

  def mailer_variables
    @site_name = params[:site_name]
    @convert_site_name = @site_name == "attorney" ? "Atty." : @site_name.downcase
  end
end
```

Confirmations Controller

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  protected

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    if signed_in?(resource_name)
      site_account_users_path(@site_name)
    else
      site_login_path(@site_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: params[:site_name] is used in the mailer since params[:site_type] will cause another error during registration. Not quite sure why but site_name works.

Comment: I suspect that the error is this, but it's difficult to say without seeing the controller that triggers the email:

The params that `ApplicationMailer` receives are not the same as the params that the controller (what sends the email) has access to, which is why you're getting `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`; because the mailer is not getting any params. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: Hi @CassandraS.,
Thank you for your time. I updated the question adding the routes to the confirmation links.
As for the controller, already included it in the question. The confirmations controller. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code; post code, instead. Try debugging in the `ApplicationMailer` before the `@site_name`; I suspect `params` is `nil`. `@site_name` in your `ConfirmationsController` is probably `nil` too.